# LU factorisation of singular matrix

Tags: numerical-methods

Is it possible to LU factorise a singular matrix. If this can be done in multiple ways, then how would you go about finding the different decompositions?

Comment: Read the section [*Existence and Uniqueness*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Existence_and_uniqueness)

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. How would you go about finding the decomposition though, and at what point in the algorithm would you have a choice which could lead to multiple outcomes?

Comment: You want to look up Doolittle's Method, Crout's Method and Cholesky's Method. Oops, should have also mentioned Wilkinson's Method. Regards

Comment: Thank you, these are useful, I am confident I will be able to solve my problem.

Comment: You are very welcome, and you can always post follow-up questions if things go South! Great luck!